# Pandas take daily mean within resampled date

Tags: pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with trip counts every 20 minutes during a whole month, let's say:

```
        Date                Trip count
0    2019-08-01 00:00:00          3
1    2019-08-01 00:20:00          2
2    2019-08-01 00:40:00          4
3    2019-08-02 00:00:00          6
4    2019-08-02 00:20:00          4
5    2019-08-02 00:40:00          2
```

I want to take daily mean of all trip counts every 20 minutes. Desired output (for above values) looks like:

```
    Date        mean
0   00:00:00    4.5
1   00:20:00    3
2   00:40:00    3
..
72  23:40:00    ..
```

Comment: There are always `00, 20, 40` minutes only?

Comment: Yes, there is always 00,20,40 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate by times created by [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html), because there are always `00, 20, 40` minutes only and no seconds:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.time).mean()
#alternative
#df1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).mean()
print (df1)
          Trip count
Date                
00:00:00         4.5
00:20:00         3.0
00:40:00         3.0
```